# Calling controller function redirects to a blank page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a several fieldsets in my view, each fieldset has a `submit` button

```
<button class="next action-button" type="submit" name="next" data-gotostep="3">(Save & Next)</button>
```

The buttons call this route

```
Route::get('worksteps/store/{subprocess_id}', 'WorkstepsController@store')->name('worksteps.store');
```

store function

```
public function store(StoreWorkstepRequest $request)
{
    
    $created_by_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $value = $request->target_value;
    $unit  = $request->unit;
    $subprocess_id = $request->subprocess_id;
    $step_position = $request->subprocess_step_position;
    $step_system_id = $request->subprocess_system_id;
    $registry_date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

    DB::table('subprocess_registry')->updateOrInsert(
        ['subprocess_id' => $step_system_id],
        ['value' => $value,
         'unit' => $unit,
         'step_position' => $step_position,
         'created_at' => $registry_date,
         'created_by_id' => $created_by_id,
        ]
    );

    return back();
  
}
```

Everything works as expected except the `return back();` line that redirects to a blank white page
I just need to call the store method without returning anything and without making any changes to the view.

Tried

```
return back();
return redirect()->back();
return redirect()->previous();
```

They all redirect back a blank page, also tried to completely remove the return statement.
How can I call the `store` function in sort of in background without affecting the `view`?

Comment: If you want it as a background process you could use a job: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#creating-jobs

Comment: As a side note, for debugging this try using `dd(redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl());` to actually see where we we are being placed back to.

Comment: Please show us the <form> Tag.

Comment: @JoshBolton i tried adding : void to the funtion and removing the return , it also results in a white screen

Comment: @Henning
 `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('frontend.worksteps.store',['subprocess_id' => $workstep->subprocess_id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="msform" class="mr-5 ml-5">
        @csrf`

Comment: @MatthewBradley I don't want to be redirected back anywhere, I just need to call the function without any changes on the view.

Comment: You need AJAX to achieve this.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm Any suggestions/links how to call controller function from a script?

Comment: @JessicaKimble Adding :void to the function is just stating that the functions return type should be void. I would suggest either AJAX or Laravel Jobs to achieve this. To call the controller method from the view, you just need the URL of the route. Something like this: https://dev.to/codeanddeploy/laravel-8-ajax-example-step-by-step-tutorial-4ic0

Comment: @JessicaKimble You are not calling controller method directly, you are calling route from Laravel, I have posted answer with AJAX.

Comment: I didn’t do blade frontends for a while but is it correct that the rote is named worksteps.store but the action of the form points to frontend.worksteps.store? Please check the generated HTML what is in the action attribute of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it with AJAX:

First add jquery:

Change the button type to button so that it doesn't try to submit the form in the traditional manner:

```
<button class="next action-button" type="button" name="next" data-gotostep="3">(Save & Next)</button>
```

AJAX submit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next.action-button').on('click', function() {
        var subprocess_id = $(this).data('gotostep'); // Retrieve subprocess_id from the button data attribute
        $.ajax({
            url: '/worksteps/store/' + subprocess_id,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                target_value: $('input[name="target_value"]').val(),
                unit: $('input[name="unit"]').val(),
                subprocess_id: $('input[name="subprocess_id"]').val(),
                subprocess_step_position: $('input[name="subprocess_step_position"]').val(),
                subprocess_system_id: $('input[name="subprocess_system_id"]').val(),
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in your controller you should return JSON:

```
return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Data saved successfully']);
```